# Why this mongoose unique index is not working?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this basic entity in mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ParticipantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    },
    survey: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Survey",
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});

ParticipantSchema.index({ email: 1, survey: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports.Participant = mongoose.models.Participant || mongoose.model("Participant", ParticipantSchema);
```

as you can see it refers to 2 other entities. The problem I have is with the unique index: when I add 2 records with the same email and survey mongo does not complain and it creates 2 identical records. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Does the index actually get created in the database? Mongoose sometimes auto-creates them, sometimes it doesn't. Not sure which is your case. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am not really interested in the index, I just would like mongo to prevent me from create 2 records with the same email and survey.

Comment: Yes, that's what unique indexes do.

Comment: well, it creates the records regardless. But I have't tried to completely delete the whole DB yet.

Comment: In this case, look into why mongoose does not create the index.

Comment: I updated the connection string in my app to create a new DB, and it worked. so yes I guess I need to recreate the DB every time I add an index, which is quite annoying. Also it works without quotes. Thanks for your help.

MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydbTest.participants index: email_1_survey_1 dup key

Comment: "so yes I guess I need to recreate the DB every time I add an index" - no, I don't think so. If this were the case, people wouldn't be running apps with mongoose in production

Comment: I guess this is because my schema is defined in mongoose. I am not really familiar with mongo but I bet doing db.collection.createIndex(); from the console will work without the need to recreate the db. Maybe this is the best practice while in production..?